# Dimension issue with scipy's curve_fit function

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm new to curve fitting in python, as well as python in general. Currently, I'm trying to use the curve_fit module from scipy to fit 4 spectroscopic peaks.

In a few words, I have data in a text file that has two columns. So my first step was to import the data into two arrays, one containing the xdata, the other the y data. Then I tried to define the function that I was going to fit (four voigt peaks). Finally, when I tried to run the whole thing, I get the following error:

> raise TypeError('Improper input: N=%s must not exceed M=%s' % (n, m))           TypeError: Improper input: N=11 must not exceed M=1

As far as I can tell from the [curve_fit help](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html#scipy.optimize.curve_fit) page, this error says that I must have at least as many data points as fit parameters, which makes sense. The problem is that my data set has 250 points in it...

Here's my code

```
import numpy as n
import pyspec as p
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

file = open('fileName', "r") #open the file
data = n.loadtxt(file) #load the file into an array
freq = n.array(data[:, 0] - n.median(data[:, 0])) #center data on zero. 
counts = n.array(data[:, 1])
error = n.array(data[:, 1]**0.5) #get the error on the counts. Standard poisson error. 

# Define a single voigt profile
def voigt(xdata, amp, cent, FWHM, ep) :
   x = xdata
   C = cent
   F = FWHM
   A = amp
   E = ep
   vmodel = A * ((1 - E)*n.exp(-2.77259 * (n.square(x - C))/n.square(F)) + E / (1 + (4 * n.square(x - C)/F**2)))
   return[vmodel]

   #Define the four peak function

def voigt4(xdata, amp1, amp2, amp3, amp4, pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4, FWHM, ep, Bg):
   voigtp1 = voigt(xdata, amp1, pos1, FWHM, ep)
   voigtp2 = voigt(xdata, amp2, pos2, FWHM, ep)
   voigtp3 = voigt(xdata, amp3, pos3, FWHM, ep)
   voigtp4 = voigt(xdata, amp4, pos3, FWHM, ep)

   voigt4 = (voigtp1 + voigtp2 + voigtp3 + voigtp4 + Bg) # include a background term
    return[voigt4]

   # give an initial guess. The *_in params are initial guesses made by the user. 
   guess =   n.array([amp1_in, amp2_in, amp3_in, amp4_in, pos1_in, pos2_in, pos3_in, pos4_in, 500, 0.5, bkgr_in])

   fit = curve_fit(voigt4, freq, counts, guess) # try to fit
```

I have no idea why that error comes up.

Comment: Try removing the brackets that you have in the return statements.  E.g. `return vmodel` and `return voigt4`.

Comment: I agree with @WarrenWeckesser: remove the brackets in your return statements and see whether that already solves the problem. In general: It would be good if you posted the data you use as well which helps to run the code and to fix the problem.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you both very much for the answer and the advice, I'll be sure to post the data if I run into anything else. Would you mind explaining why the brackets were the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already written in the comments, you should remove the brackets in your return statements in your functions `voigt` and `voigt4`. The problem with the brackets is that you put your array which you want to return in a list and thereby you reduce the dimensions of your returned object. Consider the following example:

```
import numpy as np
ar = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Then the command

```
len(ar)
```

would return 4 and

```
a[0]
```

returns 1 as expected. If you now do

```
b = [ar]
```

as you did in your return statement

```
b
```

would be

```
[array([1, 2, 3, 4])]
```

and

```
b[0]
```

not a single value anymore but the entire original array:

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

which means that you you receive and error like

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-269-33e961e0e4ea> in <module>()
----> 1 b[1]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

if you tried to access `b[1]`.

So it is then not a big surprise that you receive an error message regarding the dimensions since you reduce the multidimensional object to a one dimensional object.

Comment: Yup, this answer's my question perfectly. Incidentally, this also may help with another issue I've run in to. Thanks again!

Comment: @JulienRefour: Glad it solves the problem! Good luck with the other issue!