# Improper Input with scipy.optimize.curve_fit, multivariate regression, exponential function

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, curve-fitting

[Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Mky3MD_LOefJILrtyauKwr-QiTOIhy0H/view?usp=sharing)

```
df = pandas.read_csv(temp.csv, header=1)

def func(x1,x2,x3,a,b1,b2,b3,c):
    #return(a*np.exp(b1*x1)*np.exp(b2*x2)*np.exp(b3*x3)+c)
    return(a*np.exp(b1*x1) + b2*x2 + b3*x3 + c

def formula_tester(BIO, VAR1, VAR2, VAR3):
    X = scipy.array([VAR1, VAR2, VAR3])
    Y = scipy.array(BIO)
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, X, Y)
    return(popt)

Y = df['Biomass'] 
variable1 = df['F_cv']
variable2 = ln(df['F_d50'])
variable3 = ln(df['L_d50'])
parameters = formula_tester(Y, variable1, variable2, variable3)
parameters
```

This returns the error message

> Improper Input: N=7 must not exceed M=3

I have read the Help and a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43879801/scipy-curve-fit-multiple-series-of-data) [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39644009/multivariable-non-linear-curve-fit-with-scipy) [Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769340/fitting-multivariate-curve-fit-in-python) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34864656/dimension-issue-with-scipys-curve-fit-function).  The prior answers either correct minor typos or prove unhelpful when tried (np.concatenate).

Running the script with a try/except, where except returns the lengths of the various variable arrays, reveals all to have length 162.  Where is the N=7 coming from? And I did think I was asking for 5 parameters, not 3.  Perhaps the exponential function is set up wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the doc of [curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html):

> The model function, f(x, …). It must take the independent variable as the first argument and the parameters to fit as separate remaining arguments.

Here the independent variable has three components. The model should look like

```
def func(x, a, b1, b2, b3, c):
    return a*np.exp(b1*x[0]) + b2*x[1] + b3*x[2] + c
```